# Unable to Run Topic Modeling in Orange - Icon does not appear within Text Mining Add-on

Tags: python, anaconda, orange, orange-api

Sorry I am a Novice to Orange and have a very basic question. I just downloaded Orange 3.26 and installed the Text Mining Add-on through the Orange Command Prompt `conda install -c conda-forge orange3-text`. However, I am not able to run Topic Modeling, since it doesn't appear as an icon under Text mining or on the right-click. Am i missing something ? Attaching the Snapshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. This was because my corporate fire-wall was blocking it. I got hold of my organizations Digital Certificate and placed it in Certifi folder under site-packages and it started working.